# URL Rewrite Module 2.1 redirection http to https not working

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

They changed the url rewrite Module version (URL Rewrite Module 2.1) and now the redirection from http to https is not working.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Application : Angular

System : Windows Server IIS 10

This is the web.config file (it was working for the earliest version of URL rewrite : urlrewrite2.exe)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions applyToWebDAV="false">
                    <add fileExtension=".pdf" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found that your RewriteRule works fine with the URL Rewrite 2.1. I would suggest perform IIS Reset once and see if it starts working. If the issue persists, try to check the Failed Request Tracing logs for the issue. You could share the error message/ screenshot if you got any.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I reset it and still not working

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I found the problem, when i changed the port to 80 it is working, but in my case i need to use another port 81 (because 80 is already used for another application). Can I redirect from port 80 to port 81?

Comment: So do you mean you need a URL Rewrite rule for `http://example.com:80` to `http://example.com:81` or for `http://example.com:80` to `https://example.com:81`? Kindly clarify it, it may help us understand your requirement.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I want a redirection from http:// example.com:80 to https:// example.com:443 because now when i want to open example.com i get this error "Requested URL example.com:80" . For info, i'm using the port 81 for the http and 443 for the https.

Answer (score 0):

For `http://example.com:80` to `https://example.com:443` your rule posted in the question is correct and working fine on my side.

If it is not working on your side, you could check the Failed Request Tracing logs might give you the information about the issue. The issue might be something else.

For `http://example.com:81` to `https://example.com:443`, you could refer to the rule below.

```
<rule name="Redirect with port" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*):81$" />
     </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:443/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Let me know if you have further questions.